# Avoiding Backtracking with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a function parser in JavaScript that roughly requires the following to be true for a sequence of text to be considered a function:

- contain a camel case name (starting with a lowercase character that is not a number)
- can have parameters (parentheses are optional if no parameters are present)
- parameter names need to have the same properties as the name of the function and there can be more than one parameter, separated by a comma(s)
- return variable names are optional and can be specified with '->' after the function definition (i.e. someFunc(var1)->retVal or someFunc->retVal. They need to have the same properties as the function name.

Now assuming I get a string of text containing function definitions (some valid, some invalid) like the following:

```
somefunc(var1,var2),SomeFunc,somefunc()->RetVal,somefunc()->retVal,somefunc->retVal
```

This can be parsed using the following regex:

```
((?:\b[a-z]\w*)\(?(?:[a-z]\w*,?)*\)?(?:->[a-z]\w*)?(?=,|$))+
```

Which will extract the following function definitions from it:

- somefunc(var1,var2)
- somefunc()->retVal
- somefunc->retVal

Now, even though my regex works fine, I believe I might have some issues with backtracking based on some debugging using [this](https://regex101.com) regex testing website. For example, I believe there's a lot of backtracking going on when the regex hits `SomeFunc` in the string above.

Is there a way I can optimize this regular expression? If so, are there any guidelines I can apply to my regular expressions in the future, to make them more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's generally a bad idea to parse with RegEx.** RegEx was not made for parsing, it's made for searching and matching. Because of this, it's very bad at parsing (as well as inefficient).

It looks like you're trying to generate documentation? Have you considered using [JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc)? It's a way of writing JS comments that will generate documentation for you. There are code editors (WebStorm) that generate the actual comments for you, too.

Sorry if this isn't what you wanted to hear, but it helped me out when I was trying to do the same thing. :)

---

**EDIT: For Googler's, here's advice on preventing backtracking:**

> **How do I prevent backtracking from happening?**
>
> Do not use nested constructs that have `+` or `*`! For example,
> `([a-z]+)*` is a badly-written construct that could be rewritten as
> `[a-z]*` without changing the logic.
>
> Applying this to our example above means the regex
> `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)$` should be changed to
> `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` to avoid a nested hierarchy. This
> adjustment means it only takes around 132 iterations for a string of
> length 30 instead of 1 billion! Sounds much better, right?

More information and examples are available at the source: https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/checking-strings-avoiding-catastrophic-backtracking-1482810891360

Comment: I'm in the early stages of development, so I haven't documented any code (in fact there isn't any code to document yet :D). Thanks for the tip regardless though.

As for my original question, you wouldn't suggest using RegEx to even extract groups? Should I just go with the string functions in JavaScript to extract the function definitions?

Comment: You're welcome! No, I wouldn't use it for groups, personally. If you're sure they'll all be separated by commas, you can easily get an array of the definitions by using [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/0tdgqLdb/

Comment: Yeah that's the direction I was planning on going based on your answer. Looks like parts of the string depend on the others, which probably means I'll need a CFG parser. Thank you for the second set of eyes!

Comment: @PrestonBadeer I (a downvoter) came here because of the title of the question, and found no answer at all.

Comment: For those coming here looking for regex answers, unrelated to the OP situation that was resolved, I've added information to the post. Thanks for letting me know @ShayanToqraee

Comment: @PrestonBadeer Please use code blocks (``) for the regex you've written (or quoted), so it is displayed correctly, and the `*` does not disappear and make text italic.